# how to pass the configuration item from ansible playbook to snow

Tags: ansible, servicenow

Can anyone help to pass the configuration item to change from playbook. I was able to create the change, but configuration item is not  reflecting under change . I attached my playbook
[image]. And  also want to pass the planned start date and end date

Comment: It would help people to assist, if you provided some detail as to what you have in place, what exactly you have tried to get this working and what, if any, errors/debug information you have collected.

Answer (score 0):

Under your data block, You can add

```js
data:
  short_description: "Test"
  priority : 2
  cmdb_ci: "Email"
  start_date: "01/02/2019 00:00:00"
  end_date  "01/02/2019 03:00:00"
```

You can use any REST API tools to access Service Now tables which could give you the correct column names.

Comment: yes..Thank you. Even if we right click and check inspect element, will get the id of the element. There we can find the snow variables